# Sphinx autofunction generate python docstring without newlines

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a simple python package with 1 module containing the following function:

```
def sample_addition(num1=1, num2=2):
    """adding 2 numbers as an example

    this function will add 2 numbers in case of failre it will raise an exception
    @param num1: first number
    @type num1: float
    @param num2: second number
    @type num2: float
    @return: addition result
    @rtype: float
    """
    return num1 + num2
```

When using `.. autofunction:: sample_addition` and `make html` it results in:

```
general.sample_addition(num1=1, num2=2)
adding 2 numbers as an example

this function will add 2 numbers in case of failre it will raise an exception @param num1: first number @type num1: float @param num2: second number @type num2: float @return: addition result @rtype: float
```

I have installed and used `sphinx_epytext` inside the `conf.py -> extensions` but it didn't help to convert and show the Epytext properly

**Question:**

How can i allow it to see the new lines from the docstring?

Comment: Down-voter care to explain downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like markdown and rst, it requires newline to seperate differert paragraphs, you need to add newline between `this function...` and `@param ...` like this:

```
def sample_addition(num1=1, num2=2):
    """adding 2 numbers as an example

    this function will add 2 numbers in case of failre it will raise an exception

    @param num1: first number
    @type num1: float
    @param num2: second number
    @type num2: float
    @return: addition result
    @rtype: float
    """

return num1 + num2
```